# How to marshal the type of "Cstring" in .NET Compact Framework(C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, marshalling, cstring

### How to marshal the type of "Cstring" in .NET Compact Framework(C#)?

DLLname:Test_Cstring.dll(OS is WinCE 5.0),source code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetStringLen(CString str)
{ 
   return str.GetLength();
}
```

I marshal that in .NET Compact Framework(C#),for example:

```
[DllImport("Test_Cstring.dll", EntryPoint = "GetStringLen", SetLastError = true)]
public extern static int GetStringLen(string s);

private void Test_Cstring()
{
   int len=-1;
   len=GetStringLen("abcd");
   MessageBox.Show("Length:"+len.ToString()); //result is -1,so PInvoke is unsuccessful!
}
```

The Method of "GetStringLen" in .NET CF is unsuccessful!
 How to marshal this type of "Cstring"?
 Any information about it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't marshal `CString` as it's not a native type - it's a C++ class that wraps up a `char` array.

You can marshal `string` to `char[]` as `char[]` is a native type. You need to have the parameters to the function you want to P/Invoke into as basic types like `int`, `bool`, `char` or `struct`, but not classes. Read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx

In order to call functions that take CString as an argument you can do something like this:

```
//Compile with /UNICODE
extern "C" MFCINTEROP_API int GetStringLen(const TCHAR* str) {
  CString s(str);
  return s.GetLength();
  //Or call some other function taking CString as an argument
  //return CallOtherFunction(s);
}

[DllImport("YourDLL.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public extern static int GetStringLen(string param);
```

In the above P/Invoke function we pass in a `System.String` which can marshal to `char*/wchar_t*`. The unmanaged function then creates a instance of `CString` and works with that.

By default `System.String` is marshalled to `char*`, so be careful with what kind of string the unmanaged version takes. This version uses `TCHAR`, which becomes `wchar_t` when compiled with `/UNICODE`. That's why you need to specify `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode` in the `DllImport` attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I have a Dll with nonsource-code,the dll's head file is
give the type of "Cstring" in dllexport-table.Now I have no option but to wrap this Dll in C++(MFC static-Dll)??

Answer (score 0):

you should do the following:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetStringLen(LPCTSTR  str)
{ 
   CString s(str);
   return s.GetLength();
}
```

The CString is actually an MFC type not a native type. Just grab the string and turn it into a CString in native method.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I have a Dll with nonsource-code,the dll's head file is
give the type of "Cstring" in dllexport-table.Now I have no option but to wrap this Dll in C++(MFC static-Dll) again??