# CString GetLength() method strange behavior

Tags: string, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CString variable named strManID and value is "000".

When I calculate the length

```
int len = strManID.GetLength();
```

[image]

I got a very large value...
How is this possible?

**Edit:**
One more thing this code was executing fine in vc++ exe. Now I have made it as MFC DLL. Using this dll in my C# code.And also pass the value as string in strManID.

Program.cs

```
ImportFunc.func1(2, str, "000");
```

IntropFunc.cs

```
[DllImport("FW",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int BinFileCreate(int argc,  string[] argv, string strManID);
```

FW.cpp

```
int FW::func1(int argc, char *argv[], CString strManID)
{

    int len = strManID.GetLength();

    //Code here....
}
```

Comment: How do you "calculate the length"? Just call GetLength()?

Comment: Yes I am using GetLength() method.

Comment: You have taken that screenshot after the assignment to `len` has run, right?

Comment: yes...possibility of garbage value is none.

Comment: Is your breakpoint RIGHT after len is calculated? If not then len's memory could be being overwritten by something else.

Comment: Are you building in Debug mode? Watched variables in Release mode can give very strange answers.

Comment: See the edit part....

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I have already check this...

Comment: You cannot import CString directly since CString doesn't exist in .Net. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801134/how-to-marshal-the-type-of-cstring-in-net-compact-frameworkc for details.

Comment: OT: Down vote is the new fashion here.